# vba code to click on check boxes-2 using selenium Firefox

Tags: vba, selenium, firefox

I want to click on check box 2. I am using firefox selenium. Below is the vba code which I tried

```
driver.FindElementByXPath("//div[@id='pt_opt']/a[2]").Click
```

but I am getting error:

```
Run-time error'13':Unknown erro element is not clickable at    
point(258,10).other element would receive the click:<header id="Header-wrap" 
class="RosHeadosrch"></header>
```

Below is the html code.

```html
</div
<div id="pt_opt" class="optionBox chkbx f12"> 
<a val="6" href="javascript:void(0)" class="ptbx"><b></b><em>Ready to Move</em></a>
<a val="2" href="javascript:void(0)" class="ptbx"><b></b><em>Within 3 months</em></a>
<a val="3" href="javascript:void(0)" class="ptbx"><b></b><em>Within 6 months</em></a>
<a val="4" href="javascript:void(0)" class="ptbx"><b></b><em>Within 1 Year</em></a>
<a val="7" href="javascript:void(0)" class="ptbx"><b></b><em>Within 1-2 Years</em></a>
<a val="5" href="javascript:void(0)" class="ptbx"><b></b><em>Within 2-3 Years</em></a>
<a val="1" href="javascript:void(0)" class="ptbx"><b></b><em>New Launch</em></a>
<input type="hidden" id="posession_time" name="posession time" class="hidEle" autocomplete="off" val="" value="">    
</div>
<div class="clr pdt10"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Most likely that error is due to another element covering the element you are trying to click. Are you sure there isn't some popup or loading element covering the element when the page first loads?

Comment: Also, please post the entire error message and format it as a quote, e.g. preface it with > so it's more visible.